# Can someone explain community wiki?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

I'm confused by the frequently used designation *community wiki*. What does it entail? How do questions and answers become community wiki? What are the guidelines for it? I checked the FAQ and it's not there, but seems like it should be.

For example, [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/295/best-sites-to-share-photo-galleries-with-friends) is a community wiki and so are all the answers, including mine, but I never made my answer community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently the most complete reference for the 'what,' 'how,' and 'why' of community wiki:

[**What are “Community Wiki” posts?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Nice reference!

Comment: Thanks! Though it would be nice if all that stuff were a bit more consolidated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, community wiki should perhaps be in the FAQ, although everything can't be in the FAQ. Let's see what this thread can produce that might be used there.

Making a question community wiki is used for example when there can be no single answer to the question. Some questions that otherwise would be closed as subjective, might survive as community wiki.

Answers to a community wiki question is also automatically community wiki.

Comment: It should *definitely* be in the FAQ. It's a term used all over on the site, and if I (who has the highest or second-highest rep here) don't understand it, I think that's a signal that it needs explaining to many people. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a community wiki is used for questions that don't have a specific answer, or are combining the ideas of the community.

A question can be made community wiki either by:

- being marked as such by original poster
- editing (enough edits to a post and it becomes a CW)
- being marked as such by a moderator

Generally any question [asking for a list of answers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-are-must-have-accessories) should be marked as community wiki, since there is no correct answer.  Also, and question that [asks for multiple answers (such as a favorite X)](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/402/who-is-your-favorite-photographer-and-why).