# Community Wikis availability

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-wikis, community-wiki

If [Community Wikis aren't to be part of the FAQ](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/can-someone-explain-community-wiki/231#231), can we get some link on the home page to see the various wikis? A page of Wikis, similar to FAQs but ongoingly updated. (IMHO this may reduce the "what is the best camera" type questions, and the other repetitious questions coming through.)

I have tried to search the tags for wiki, with no results. The posts search for "community wiki" resulted in 19 posts.

To me it seems these should be more accessible, as the community wikis usually provide a lot of information, as this site is about good content, shouldn't the good content (wikis) be given prominence?

Answer (score 2):

The **good** wikis get lots of votes, and that's how they get the prominence they *deserve*. Marking a post as community wiki should not automatically promote it, especially given that CW is often used for cases that *don't* fit the StackExchange format well.

You can search for community wikis using StackExchange Data Explorer, there is already a query for Community Wiki [questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/photography/s/1258/community-wiki-questions) but you can always build (and share) your own queries.